# Error trying to access SmartCloud using OAuth

Tags: oauth, ibm-sbt

I'm trying to use the Social Business Toolkit to access SmartCloud using OAuth, but I'm getting this error. Using `SmartCloudBasicEndpoint` everything works fine.

```
[4/4/14 12:01:56:236 CEST] 00000038 SBTProxy      I   URL computed from SBTProxy is https://apps.na.collabserv.com/communities/service/atom/oauth/communities/all
[4/4/14 12:01:56:556 CEST] 00000038               E com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.OAuth1Handler _performOAuth1Dance Failed to get request token. requestUrl:https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth/getRequestToken, authorizeUrl: https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth/authorizeToken, accessUrl: https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth/getAccessToken, callback: null, truncated key:a919....1b25, truncated secret:9054....687d. OAuth callback is empty, please check with your application vendor to ensure a callback is not required.

                                 com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.OAuthException: Internal error - getRequestToken failed Exception: <br>
    at com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.OAuth1Handler.getRequestTokenFromServer(OAuth1Handler.java:169)
    at com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.OAuth1Handler._performOAuth1Dance(OAuth1Handler.java:656)
    at com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.OAuth1Handler.performOAuth1Dance(OAuth1Handler.java:649)
    at com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.OAuth1Handler._acquireToken(OAuth1Handler.java:625)
    at com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.OAuth1Handler.acquireToken(OAuth1Handler.java:580)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.endpoints.OAuthEndpoint.authenticate(OAuthEndpoint.java:234)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.forceAuthentication(ClientService.java:281)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.processResponse(ClientService.java:1123)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService._xhr(ClientService.java:1041)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.execRequest(ClientService.java:1006)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.xhr(ClientService.java:966)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.get(ClientService.java:842)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.get(ClientService.java:838)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.BaseService.retrieveData(BaseService.java:352)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.BaseService.retrieveData(BaseService.java:376)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.BaseService.retrieveData(BaseService.java:327)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.BaseService.getEntities(BaseService.java:187)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.communities.CommunityService.getPublicCommunities(CommunityService.java:164)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.communities.CommunityService.getPublicCommunities(CommunityService.java:146)
    at servlets.SmartCloudTestServlet.doGet(SmartCloudTestServlet.java:82)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.ibm.sbt.util.SBTFilter.doFilter(SBTFilter.java:53)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3751)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1690)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:197)
    at com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.OAuth1Handler.getRequestTokenFromServer(OAuth1Handler.java:156)
    ... 51 more

[4/4/14 12:01:56:560 CEST] 00000038 SystemOut     O Problem Occurred while fetching public communities: Problem occurred while fetching public communities
```

Here's what I've done so far:

- Create a new Servlet application.
- I'm using `RuntimeFactoryStandalone`.
- Added `managed-beans.xml` and `sbt.properties` (both from samples app) to `/WEB-INF/`.
- I'm running the application on WebSphere Application Server. (I also tried the same code in a Portlet on WebSphere Portal)
- Added the SmartCloud key, secret and appId to the properties file.

I'm using this code:

```
try {
    CommunityService svc = new CommunityService("smartcloud");
    CommunityList communities = svc.getPublicCommunities();

    System.out.println("Listing public communities , Total communities found : " + communities.getTotalResults());
} catch (Throwable e) {
    System.out.println("Problem Occurred while fetching public communities: " + e.getMessage());
    //e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm getting the same error if I manually use a `SmartCloudOAuthEndpoint`.

Am I forgetting something here?

***Update:***

My manual endpoint:

```
SmartCloudOAuthEndpoint endpoint = new SmartCloudOAuthEndpoint();
endpoint.setUrl("https://apps.na.collabserv.com");
endpoint.setConsumerKey("a91..----REMOVED FOR STACKOVERFLOW----..");
endpoint.setConsumerSecret("905..----REMOVED FOR STACKOVERFLOW----..");
endpoint.setRequestTokenURL("https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth/getRequestToken");
endpoint.setAuthorizationURL("https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth/authorizeToken");
endpoint.setAccessTokenURL("https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth/getAccessToken");
endpoint.setAppId("RonnieTest");
endpoint.setApiVersion("apiVersion");
//endpoint.setHttpProxy("localhost:8888");
endpoint.setForceTrustSSLCertificate(true);
endpoint.setSignatureMethod("PLAINTEXT");
endpoint.setCredentialStore("SmartCloudStore");
endpoint.setAuthenticationService("communities/service/atom/communities/my");
```

I'm using this Internal App in SmartCloud:
[image]

Comment: OAuth callback is empty, please check with your application vendor to ensure a callback is not required. - that's the error, it looks like you aren't getting a callback passed, I'll ask the team to look at it

Comment: did you use an OAuth2 Key? or an OAuth Key? that might be worth double checking to see you copied the right keys

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply again. I edited my question and added some addition information. Could it be that `setForceTrustSSLCertificate` is causing this issue?

Comment: Also there's one part I don't really understand, maybe that's the part I forgot to implement. In the Playground a user gets 'forwarded' to a login screen (/sbt/loginForm.html?.. or the SmartCloud login) and after logging in, back to the API result. Is this the callback?
Is showing the login page and redirecting a user back to my application something the Social Business Toolkit will do for me? I couldn't really find anything in the documentation or the SBT sites about that.

Comment: Oh btw, if I use Fiddler as proxy, I see the SBT calling the communities URL (`https://apps.na.collabserv.com/communities/service/atom/oauth/communities/all`), but it's not calling any of the OAuth Token urls. So I doubt the problem is in SmartCloud not sending me a callback for example.

Comment: you have to set the callback.... have you thought about using the EndpointFactory.find method to have it automatically create the endpoint for you from the managed-beans.xml?

Comment: I'll try that for now, but eventually I'd like to save all Endpoint settings as Portlet Preferences and not use the managed-beans.xml at all.

How do I set the callback? I assumed it was an endpoint property, but I can only find a `setCallBackUrl` in `OAuthHandler.java` and no idea how to reach that. If you can point me to a blog post or YouTube movie explaining how to do it, that would be great as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I wasn't passing `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` to my `Context`. Turns out that `getCallbackUrl(Context context)` in `OAuthHandler` is the first method that actually needs the request to build the callback URL.